# Cassandra node storage is corrupted

Tags: cassandra

I have a 2 Datacenter of cluster, where replication factor of X-2 and Y-1,

From the Datacenter X: the data of one node is corrupted or destroyed.

I have replaced the storage device from the machine , now i have same node but no data .

I want to attach this node again to Datacenter - X , but i don't know how the data will gets replicated to this node or how the consistency gets maintained for the data loss by the node.

I am aware of Node replacement of datacenter , but i don't know about storage replacement with the same node.

Answer (score 1):

You have if I got it right 3 replicas of your data so you should be fine.

If your node lost is storage, consider it a dead node which you can replace the same way you would replace an entirely dead node as described here:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

Update:
In your case you lost the node in cassandra terms as you lost it's data on ssd so it is dead for your cluster. Your physical node remains intact you only replace your disk.

Now, if you had a backup - simply restore it (/var/lib/cassandra/* and the /etc/cassandra/*) and run a repair and your are done.

If not go the same way as replacing a node, setup cassandra, place your configs and start cassandra. But very likely you will see something like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node with address /10.20.30.40 already exists,
cancelling join. Use cassandra.replace_address if you want to replace this node.
```

Huh? Cassandra still knows there was a node with that ip address and refuse joining. You need to update cassandra-env.sh with:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.replace_address=10.20.30.40"
```

A last thing that could occur - your node does not bootstrap automatically. This happens when the node was a seed node. In this case run `nodetool rebuild`.

Comment: That is ok to replace the node with new node. but looking for better option to replace storage in the same node. The node has no issue only the ssd got corrupted

Comment: I will add some more details to my answer above.